# Problem attached objects top Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to attached objects such as email and text files to google sheets similar to in excel but I cannot figure out how to use the feature if it exists in sheets.

I've tried all of the addons existing on my sheets and none are working.

I want it to look like the image below, I can double click on the icon and it then opens the text file or email file. I just want to recreate this in sheets if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is usually done by inserting Drawing or Image and then hyperlink it with formula or with a script

[image: 0]

[image: 0]